# export datasets into multiple sheets of one excel file in sas

Tags: sas

I'm use this code

```
proc export data=goldsheet_invalid outfile="C:\Documents and Settings\sasadm\Desktop\gold.xls" dbms=xls replace;
sheet="gold";
run;

proc export data=platinumsheet_invalid outfile="C:\Documents and Settings\sasadm\Desktop\gold.xls" dbms=xls replace;
sheet="platinum";
run;

proc export data=titaniumsheet_invalid outfile="C:\Documents and Settings\sasadm\Desktop\gold.xls" dbms=xls replace;
sheet="titanium";
run;
```

> Error:Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order

Note:- already try dbms=xlsx or dbms=EXCELCS but not work

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code that I can see.  What is the error pointing to in the log?  Does any `dbms=xls` work (without the sheet names etc.) or do you perhaps have some problem with your excel installation?

Comment: dbms=xls work without the sheetname but after write sheetname we got the error

Comment: Okay, but what else is there in the error?  It should show you what it's complaining about; and, I wouldn't be shocked to see more errors than that one line.  You might also add what SAS version you're on. SAS 9.4 has no problem with running that code sheet included.

Comment: Error:-Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.i am using sas 9.1

Comment: I disbelieve that that is the only information you're given.  At *minimum* you must have a pointer to what SAS statement exactly caused the error (a red highlight, in DM mode).

Comment: In any event, you're using SAS 9.1, that's ten plus years out of date.  I am not sure if 9.1 supports `sheet` in `dbms=xls`.  Upgrade.

Comment: 88   sheet="gold";
     -----
     180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.this statement is shown in red line

Comment: Then it sounds like 9.1. doesn't support `sheet` there.  You're very likely out of luck in 9.1 for what you're trying to do - I'm not even sure how well it supports PC Files Servers.  9.1 was the first release SAS really did even a halfway decent job with Excel, and it wasn't until 9.2 and even 9.3 that it was reasonably feature complete.

Comment: oh!! it's a version issue.thankyou for your support

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a PROC EXPORT this can be accomplished with older versions of SAS using ODS (Output Delivery System) statements.  Going this route is not as clean as the PROC EXPORT but if all you want is to get the data from these data sets to a single Excel workbook and have the results of each proc statement on a different worksheet this will do it.

In this case the code to accomplish what you are looking for would be:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file='C:\temp\gold.xml' options(sheet_name = 'Gold' sheet_interval='proc');
proc print data=goldsheet_invalid;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_name = 'Platinum');
proc print data=platinumsheet_invalid;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_name = 'Titanium');
proc print data=titaniumsheet_invalid;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

You will notice that the file extension created is XML, this is a necessity.  When you load the file in Excel is would appear as expected and feel free to update the file extension from there.

More details about SAS and ODS can be found at:  https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/TipSheet_ods_xl_xp.pdf